# How to play access and play the video programmatically?

Tags: iphone, video

I am developing an application. In that my requirement is access the video from iPhone and play that videos and select one from that videos. So please tell me how to access and play the videos in iPhone programmatically.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Have you search [play video](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+play+video)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's [MoviePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html) sample shows how to do this.

And refer - https://web.archive.org/web/20110528064432/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html

Answer (score 3):

This site is not to do your homework for you.  Please read Apple docs on [Media Player Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer).  Then download [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) from iOS Developer Library.  Once you have written your own code and getting a specific error you cannot resolve, then post your question on SO.